# Feather css icons İs not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, feather

I should use feather css icons but, icons are not working on my mvc project. I tried changing file path but it did not work again.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "feather";
  src: url('../fonts/feather.eot?t=1501841394106'); /* IE9*/
  src: url('../fonts/feather.eot?t=1501841394106#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/feather.woff?t=1501841394106') format('woff'), /* chrome, firefox */
  url('../fonts/feather.ttf?t=1501841394106') format('truetype'), /* chrome, firefox, opera, Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
  url('../fonts/feather.svg?t=1501841394106#feather') format('svg'); /* iOS 4.1- */
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "feather";
  src: url('../fonts/feather.eot?t=1501841394106'); /* IE9*/
  src: url('../fonts/feather.eot?t=1501841394106#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/feather.woff?t=1501841394106') format('woff'), /* chrome, firefox */
  url('../fonts/feather.ttf?t=1501841394106') format('truetype'), /* chrome, firefox, opera, Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
  url('../fonts/feather.svg?t=1501841394106#feather') format('svg'); /* iOS 4.1- */
}

.feather {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'feather' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-alert-octagon:before { content: "\e81b"; }

.icon-alert-circle:before { content: "\e81c"; }

.icon-activity:before { content: "\e81d"; }

.icon-alert-triangle:before { content: "\e81e"; }

.icon-align-center:before { content: "\e81f"; }

.icon-airplay:before { content: "\e820"; }

.icon-align-justify:before { content: "\e821"; }

.icon-align-left:before { content: "\e822"; }

.icon-align-right:before { content: "\e823"; }
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you check in your browser that when it downloads the font, it ends with HTTP 200 and not 404? The real question: are you really sure your URI are correct? If I were you, I would check the request the browser makes, understand from that why the URL is wrong, and fix the URI in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-Origin Request Blocked(Reason: CORS request not http). it occurs locally you can download feather font and just paste font files in your respected fonts folder and replace your urls with new files and done.

Comment: Seems that OP uses this approach since there's "../fonts/" in url